# PHP if checkbox was checked and now wasn't (and opposite)?

Tags: php, checkbox, if-statement

I am thinking this is doable? Maybe?

Here is my checkbox input:

```
<input  type='checkbox' name='cb_name' id='cb_name' checked='checked' />
```

I Need an if else statement that checks only if the Checkbox was changed.

I have other input fields on the form. And if the checkbox wasn't touched or checked, then SAVE the form without doing the checkbox condition.

If checkbox was checked before and now is != 'checked' then do this.

&&

If checkbox was != 'checked' before and now is = 'checked' then do this.

&&

and then finally, if checkbox was left alone (NO VALUE WAS CHANGED) then do the other form stuff without running the checkbox condition statement??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you must have some reason to decide when displaying the form if the check box is checked or not. This is your initial state.

Because we don't know how you are deciding this, why not add a hidden field with the value like so, setting the value to match if the checkbox is checked (ie checked/unchecked):

```
<input type="hidden" name="cb_hidden" value="<?php print $checkedOrNot; ?>" />
```

We don't know your condition for why the checkbox is checked, however this should solve the simple idea abstractly

```
<?php
$checkedOrNot = '';
if(/* the condition that decides if things are checked */) {
    $checkedOrNot = 'checked';
}
?><input type="checkbox" name="cb_name" checked="<?php print $checkedOrNot; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="cb_hidden" value="<?php print $checkedOrNot; ?>" />
```

Then when you get your post data

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cb_name']) && $_POST['cb_hidden'] != 'checked') {
    //if the checkbox was changed to checked
} elseif(!isset($_POST['cb_name']) && $_POST['cb_hidden'] == 'checked') {
    //if the checkbox was changed to unchecked
}
```

This is a solution without needing previous state

Comment: How would I define the $checkedOrNot   ??
$checkedOrNot = "?";

Comment: its however you decided if the checkbox is checked or not, I'll edit and add some code to help

Comment: Great! So, if I change /* the condition that decides if things are checked */ to if($checkbox == "on") {   ??

Comment: sure? I don't know how or why you are choosing to set the checkbox so this is as far as I can help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can´t check if it is or is not checked.

If a checkbox is not checked, it is not submitted at all, so if you want to check for a value, you´ll have to start with something like `isset($_POST['cb_name'])`.